# Dispose of dialogwindow in backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

i'm loading screen in backgroundworker:

```
 private void LSLoadingScreen(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadingScreen ls = new LoadingScreen(this.timerStart);
        ls.ShowDialog();

        while (LoadingScreen.CancellationPending)
        {
            ls.Dispose();
            LoadingScreen.Dispose();
        }
```

but my loadingScreen doesn't dispose when i use this code in other function:

```
LoadingScreen.CancelAsync();
timerStart = false;
LoadingScreen.Dispose();
```

How to dispose it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, ShowDialog() will prevent the rest of the code executing until the dialog is closed - which you are never doing.

Even when it does close, it will evaluate the while loop (which will most likely be false so skipped) and then your backgroundworker will be finished.

If all you are doing is showing a dialog then I would just do this on the main thread, and have your loading process on the background worker..

1. Fire background worker (which does loading code)
2. Show your loading dialog
3. On BackgroundWorkerCompleted event, close your loading dialog

Try to get all your UI elements in the main UI thread.

Hope that helps

**EDIT:**

Based on your comment...

```
public partial class MainForm:Form
{
   LoadingScreen ls;

   public MainForm()
   {
   }

   public void StartLoad()
   {
      ls = new LoadingScreen(this.timerStart);
      backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
      ls.Show();
   }

   void backgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
      //Loading code goes here
   }

   void BackgroundWorkerMainRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
      if(ls != null)
         ls.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: How to make loadingscreen ls visible inside BackgroundWorker function? Where to put it's declaration? LoadingScreen ls = new LoadingScreen(this.timerStart); When i put it after: 
"public partial class MainForm : Form
 {" i'm getting error that "Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context", when i put it after   public MainForm()
        {, loading screen isn't available inside functions.. sorry for stupid question.

Comment: Don't make it visible inside the Bgw, Show it just before starting the Bgw.